# Select Option dropdown not displaying selected option

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a Blazor app that populates 6 select option dropdowns with data from DB. Three of these are populated with date and time from a string list.

When I select a date and time it is not displayed in the dropdown box. After selecting a date time the dropdown is blank, but the value is actually selected and binding works. It's just not displayed.

If I remove "bind=@..." it displays correctly.
Have anyone else experienced this, and how did you solve it?

```
<select bind="@Innput.Klokkeslett1">
                        <option value="@(0)">Tid1</option>
                        @foreach (var tid1 in tidListe)
                        {
                            <option value="@tid1">@tid1</option>
                        }
                    </select>
```

Comment: Please, show all your code...

Answer (score 4):

Two things to note, `select` uses a string value, and that value needs to match the `option` value.
So, if your field Innput.Klokkeslett1 is a DateTime, you will need  to use a property to handle the binding / conversion between string and DateTime.
If you ensure you use an explicit date format for the `option` values, and your property returns it's value in the same date format, then the select will be able to match it's `value` to one of it's `option` `values` and display the corresponding text, which can be formatted any way you like.

```
<select bind="@MySelectProxy">
    <option value="@(0)">Tid1</option>
    @foreach (var tid1 in tidListe)
    {
        <option value="@tid1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")">@tid1</option>
    }
</select>

@functions
{
string MySelectProxy {
  get => Innput.Klokkeslett1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  set => DateTime.TryParse(value, out Innput.Klokkeslett1); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried your sollution but it got me thinking, and I discovered I had made a silly mistake in my code by filling dates from the DB into a string list, and this caused some problems. Once I changed this to a Datetime list in the controller and so on, it solved everything, and now the dates are showing correctly when selected

Comment: Might help others struggling: You *need* to use Blazor code in your <option> for the rebind to work. Took me forever to discover. So use a @foreach when populating your <options> like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="@ComboSelectionChanged">
        <option value="0" selected>
            @list[0]
        </option>
        @for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">
                @list[i]
            </option>
        }
    </select>    

public void ComboSelectionChanged(UIChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out int index))
        {
            SelectedStyleIndex = index
             //now you know which one is selected

        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not answer his question as to why the selected item is not displayed, though " the value is actually selected and binding works".

Comment: Incidentally, this is what Steve Senderson has to say about what you did: "If it was me, I wouldn't want to be using the onchange events, parsing ints, and generally relying on the DOM to track the selected index of the dropdowns. Instead of all that, I'd prefer to model the selections in C# and use Blazor's two-way bindings to sync with the DOM".

Comment: This is simple and working solution, you can continue looking for better way. I did what I could. Second answer below looks better.

Comment: Second answer won't work as of version 3 Blazor, UIChangeEventArgs were deprecated.